# Objective-C: Status bar color and navigation color is not being same even I set same color in iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios11

> Sorry for Lengthy description-

On which Application I am working, it is 2 years old. As we wanted to give support for iOS 11. On particular view controller, we needed to rotate the screen with 180degree. 
For this we used-

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

> By this way we actually transform the window.

It was working fine before iOS11.0. In iOS 11 when we again transform to original view then there is the problem with the status bar.

So, to resolving this issue I am changing the color of **Navigation Bar** as well as **Status Bar**,

```
#import "UINavigationController+Utilities.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (Utilities)

UIView *view;

-(void)setStatusBackground:(UIColor *)color
{
    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"11.0"))
    {

        if (view == nil) {

            view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, DEVICE_SCREEN_WIDTH, 20)] ;
            view.backgroundColor = color;
            [self.view addSubview:view];
        }

        view.backgroundColor = color;

    }
}

@end
```

> Change background color of the navigation bar to Blue.

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: HCCOLOR_BLUE];
    [self.navigationController setStatusBackground:HCCOLOR_BLUE];

but the color is not same both. It looks little different.

I am adding the image-[image: Screen shot of navigation bar]

Answer (score 0):

This could be because might be your navigation bar is translucent 
Try `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`